# Execute SparkCore function using Gobot.io and sleepy RESTful Framework for Go

Tags: rest, go, sparkcore, gobot.io

I have the following bit of code where I'm using the RESTful framework for Go called [sleepy](https://github.com/dougblack/sleepy).

I can successfully start the service at: http://localhost:3000, however when I try to access http://localhost:3000/temperature I'm expecting my [SparkCore](http://docs.spark.io/api/#introduction-calling-a-function) function `dht` to execute.

I'm using the [Gobot.io Spark platform](http://gobot.io/documentation/platforms/spark/) to execute this function based on [this example](https://github.com/hybridgroup/gobot/blob/master/examples/spark_core_function.go), which I've implemented in my own code.

The problem is that the code doesn't get past the `gobot.Start()` method inside the `Get()` function so I can't actually return the `result` data.

I'm setting the `data` value hoping that I can do the:

```
return 200, data, http.Header{"Content-type": {"application/json"}}
```

But it never gets called becuase of the `gobot.Start()`.

I'm very new to Go so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
package main

import (
    "net/url"
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/dougblack/sleepy"
    "github.com/hybridgroup/gobot"
    "github.com/hybridgroup/gobot/platforms/spark"
)

var gbot = gobot.NewGobot()
var sparkCore = spark.NewSparkCoreAdaptor("spark", "device_id", "auth_token")

type Temperature struct {}
func (temperature Temperature) Get(values url.Values, headers http.Header) (int, interface{}, http.Header) {
    work := func() {
        if result, err := sparkCore.Function("dht", ""); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        } else {
            data := map[string]string{"Temperature": result}
            fmt.Println("result from \"dht\":", result)
        }
    }

    robot := gobot.NewRobot("spark",
        []gobot.Connection{sparkCore},
        work,
    )

    gbot.AddRobot(robot)
    gbot.Start()

    return 200, data, http.Header{"Content-type": {"application/json"}}
}

func main() {
    api := sleepy.NewAPI()

    temperatureResource := new(Temperature)
    api.AddResource(temperatureResource, "/temperature")

    fmt.Println("Listening on http://localhost:3000/")
    api.Start(3000)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gbot.Start()` is a blocking call.

In this context, you are expected to call it as:

```
go gbot.Start()
```

This will launch it in a goroutine (think thread) and then let your app continue.

When you look at the [gobot example app](https://github.com/hybridgroup/gobot), they don't run in the background since it is the main function. If main runs everything in the background and doesn't wait for anything, the app exits immediately with no apparent effect.

Comment: typo on my part, gbot.Start(), just add the word go in front of the line that is blocking... updating answer